# Expand variable and transform it in a quoted list

Tags: quote

The function `cycle-themes` have `cycle-themes-theme-list` as a quoted list, e.g., `(setq cycle-themes-theme-list '(tsdh-light wheatgrass whiteboard womba))`.

At the same time, `(custom-available-themes)` will return all available themes. How do I apply the `quote` to this expanded list?

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
 (use-package cycle-themes
  :ensure t
  :init (setq cycle-themes-theme-list
          (quote-after-expand (custom-available-themes))))
#+end_src
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
(setq cycle-themes-theme-list (custom-available-themes))
```

here (try it!).  `cycle-themes-theme-list` just wants a list.  The point of the quote in

```
(setq cycle-themes-theme-list '(tsdh-light wheatgrass whiteboard womba))
```

is to prevent elisp from evaluating the target list (and so treating `tsdh-light` as a function with arguments `wheatgrass`, `whiteboard` and `womba`).

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem was the package itself!